# installing cordova-plugin-googlemaps v2.2.9

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, npm-install

I am trying to install `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` version 2.2.9 for an Ionic project.

My **package.json** file reads as follows:

```
...
...
...
"dependencies": {
    .
    .
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.2.9",
    .
    .
    .
}
...
...
```

However, when I run `npm install --verbose`, the information logged reads:

```
npm info lifecycle cordova-plugin-googlemaps@2.5.1~postinstall: cordova-plugin-googlemaps@2.5.1
```

On opening the generated **package-lock.json** file, it reads:

```
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
      "version": "2.5.1",
      .
      .
      .
}
```

As it turns out, a different version of `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` is installed.

I deleted the **node_modules** folder and ran `npm i` again, but the same thing happens again and again.

When I uninstall the plugin and run `npm install cordova-plugin-googlemaps@^2.2.9`, version 2.5.1 still gets installed.

How can I resolve this? Will copying the source code of v2.2.9 into my **node_modules** folder be a viable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace caret sign with tilde :

```
cordova-plugin-googlemaps@~2.2.1
```

Comment: It still installs the latest `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` version, which is v2.5.1.

Comment: @mondieki replace caret sign with tilde : cordova-plugin-googlemaps@~2.2.1

Comment: Silly me, the syntax of semantic versioning. Thank you. If you could edit your answer to this, then I can mark it off as the accepted answer.

Comment: You are welcome, i have edited the answer, good luck @mondieki